# What is "ALG TWEAKS: Set to shipping settings" in console?

Tags: xcode, tvos

I have new TvOs project in Xcode, and ALWAYS* getting this message in 
 console.
 Googling doesn't work because I always getting result about how to 
 prepare package to shipping by post/courier. (curse you, SEO).

*always means always - pre build, after clean build folder, after 
 compile...etc

Comment: The title says it all and in the body there is one word "ALWAYS".

Comment: I am seeing this too with no results on an "ALG" search in the build settings.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any idea about that?